# 1.10.10: flag provided but not defined: -rpc

Tags: go-ethereum

There were many questions with the same title, but none of it work for me. So I have to post mine here.

```
geth --datadir ./data init Genesis.json

geth --datadir ./data --networkid 112 console --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --allow-insecure-unlock
```

The last version that was working: GETH 1.9.17

I have tried 1.10.8, 1.10.9 and 1.10.10, unfortunately none is working

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, RPC had been removed

[cmd/geth, cmd/utils: remove legacy rpc flags #23358](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/23358)